# General discussion about thread (Confusion)

Tags: java, multithreading

I just want to know what is the difference between the following two methods of invoking the thread.

Please look at the two pictures of the two scenarios

[image: Thread Implementation Scenario 1]

[image: Thread Implementation Scenario 2]

My problem is that the behavior i faced is when i follow "scenario 1" i lost control of my program and the

> "// other commands" in MyClass didnt run

when i followed scenario two my sequence was smooth. has anyone noticed this behavior or is it a malfunction?

Kindly give your opinions.

Regards,

Comment: Both are incorrect, because they don't even compile. Thread is a class, and not an interface. So you can't implement it.

Comment: What is the Thread interface in this case? In standard Java, Thread is a class, not an interface.

Comment: oh sorry guys its a big typo its not implements Thread, it is implements Runnable. hope you will ignore the mistake and will continue on the invoking mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I guess that instead of implementing `Thread` (which is not an interface as already stated) you mean to implement `Runnable`.

So the question seems to be (it's just a guess, since your question is missing): who should start the thread - `MyClass` or `MyThread`?

Basically, I'd prefer scenario 1 since `MyThread` is actually just a runnable task and should not additionally handle the thread itself.

Thus `MyClass` should create and start the thread. This would additionally allow you to keep references to the spawned threads and maybe call `join()` or other methods on them later on.

As a sidenote, I'd change `MyThread` into this: `public class MyRunnable implements Runnable { ... }`

Comment: Yes thomas i meant to implement Runbable its not thread that was a typo am sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to access the Thread object, e.g. to wait for it to finish or to poll it's state. In scenario 2 you might not do this because variable `t` is not accessible from the client code. In order to achieve this, you either had to make `t` visible from the outside code or override the `Thread` methods (which would be a bit futile). If `invokeThread` is meant as some sort of convenience method, you could consider returning `t`.

If scenario 2 is meant as "`MyThread` encapsulates running a thread and controls it's state", you don't have to extend `Thread` (which reads a bit confusing).

As mentioned in [the other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645549/general-discussion-about-thread-confusion/7645750#7645750), I would second implementing `Runnable` rather than subclassing `Thread` for cleaner code.

Comment: Chabicht i have changed the images it was a typo error it wasnt implementing Thread it was implementing Runnable sorry for this blunder

Comment: i have included my observation i noticed in my question after editing it.